# How to count and display marks in a new page in a quiz where the questions are mapped from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a quiz project using React. I have written code to display random N questions from a file containing all questions. But now I am stuck to write code that checks the selected option is correct or not and give the marking in new page.

I have a javascript file containing many no of questions just like below.

```js
const questions = [
        {
      question: "Entomology is the science that studies",
      options: ["Behavior of human beings", "Insects", "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms", "The formation of rocks"],
      answer: "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms"
     },
     {
      question: "Eritrea, which became the 182nd member of the UN in 1993, is in the continent of",
      options: ["Asia", "Africa", "Europe", "Australia"],
      answer: "Africa"
     },
      {
      question: "Hitler party which came into power in 1933 is known as",
      options: ["Labour Party", "Nazi Party", "Ku-Klux-Klan","Democratic Party"],
      answer: "Nazi Party"
     }
    ]

    export default questions;
```

Then I have a function called **shuffleArray** which uses Fisher-Yates Shuffle then I have shuffled the above questions array and stored in a constant.

I have to display 60 questions in Group A and 40 questions in Group B. So I am passing *num* to display the no of questions as it goes from 1-60 no in Group A and 1-40 in Group B when I map.

**FILE 1**

```js
requiredArray1 = this.shuffleArray(questions1).splice(0,60);
requiredArray2 = this.shuffleArray(questions2).splice(0,40);
      
this.setState({
GroupA: requiredArray1.map(item => <MCQ question={item.question} options={item.options} answer={item.answer} shuffleArray={this.shuffleArray} num={requiredArray1.indexOf(item)+1}  />),
GroupB: requiredArray2.map(item => <MCQ question={item.question} options={item.options} answer={item.answer} shuffleArray={this.shuffleArray} num={requiredArray2.indexOf(item)+61} />)
})
```

Then I have rendered it like this.

**FILE 1**

```js
<h5> GROUP A [60 * 1 = 60]</h5>
 {this.state.GroupA}
<h5> GROUP B [40 * 2 = 80]</h5>
 {this.state.GroupB}
```

The **MCQ** component has following code.

**MCQ.js**

```js
//Inside constructor
this.arr = [0,1,2,3]
this.newArr = this.props.shuffleArray(this.arr);

<h1>{this.props.num}. {this.props.question}</h1>

<label> <input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[this.newArr[0]]} /> {this.props.options[this.newArr[0]]} </label>
<label> <input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[this.newArr[1]]} /> {this.props.options[this.newArr[1]]} </label>
<label> <input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[this.newArr[2]]} /> {this.props.options[this.newArr[2]]} </label>
<label> <input type="radio" name={this.props.question} value={this.props.options[this.newArr[3]]} /> {this.props.options[this.newArr[3]]} </label>
```

**Now how can I count the marks and display it in a new page when I submit from the button located in FILE1. Similarly I want to make the questions and answers of all the questions be able to be displayed in the new page. Better alternatives and ideas are appreciable.**

**I just want to know how can I store and get the values (like question, selected option etc) of all 100 questions in new page**

Sorry if I am unclear or if I am unable to ask question clearly. I am not used to asking like this. PLZ HELP ME WITH IT.

Comment: I would add a unique id for each question to make it comparable. Now you can save the the selected answer on a submit button after selecting an input with the question id within the parent component or redux and use that to display the that in a new page.

Comment: Yeah but how do I save the selected answer and retrieve it to check the answer.

Comment: First you should wrap the inputs in a form and make it single select, so that the user can only select one answer. And the form  should have a submit button and a submit callback which will trigger the saving of the selected answer.

Comment: This is too broad question. If you can create a codepen, it will be easy to answer.

Comment: OK BRO but my website is huge and has many files what should i do ?
I have only included the portions that matters in above question.

Comment: I just want to know how can I store and get the values (like question, selected option etc) of all 100 questions in new page

Comment: @John, please read the ["https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) section from the ["Help Center"](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to create one. For these kinds of issues, is the only way someone can give you a straight answer.